# How can one use the Web Page Editor in custom RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, eclipse-wtp

I want to use the "Web Tools Editor" that is part of the Web Tools Plattform in my own RCP-Application. I think i have got some understanding on the RCP plattform by now, but I still have no clue how to access the functionality of the pagedesigner (org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner) after adding it as a dependency to my project. Has anyone some experience in adding components of the web tools plattform into an RCP-Application and can give me a hint or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a difficulty with these sorts of requests (I am, myself, trying to include this or that feature that I saw in the Eclipse IDE, every so often).

The trick is to try and identify the component you want to bring in, and then try and pull it into your project, without bringing in too many dependencies.

The first step used to be quite hard, but since 3.4 it is a matter of using the Plug-In Spy - hold down `Alt-Shift-F1` on whilst your desired component is in focus should give you a tooltip showing you the class, the bundle, etc etc.

The second step is altogether more tricky and is where I usuaully fail to get any results:

- if you are lucky then you can just include the bundle in the launch configuration/.product of your app. Once you hit Add Required Bundles, you are not left with 3000 bundles (i.e. your RCP is now Eclipse).
- usually, this is not the case, because the Eclipse team haven't refactored the bit of code you're interested in out into an RCP safe bundle. If so, then you're going to have to do that yourself.
- Again, if you are lucky then that will mean moving some classes out of the eclipse bundle into your own, including internal classes, and that will be the end of it - i.e. the dependencies of your desired functionality are all within the bundle.
- If you're unlucky, then you need to isolate/reimplement the bit of functionality that is required, and change your version of the copied code.

It is hard laborious, and pretty difficult to upgrade. I realise that none of this is what you want to hear.